# click() on input type file inside another click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file, input

So I have a button which on click triggers a function, e.g. doSomething()

```
<button type="button" onclick="doSomething()" >Add file<\button>
```

And Input with type input:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInputShp" class="fileInputShp" multiple="true" data-active="false">


function doSomething(){
some code;
...
$('#fileInputShp').click();

some further code;
ajax call;
}
```

What it is doing, it opens a file window, I can add a file and I have it in my input but the further code with ajax call won't run unless I click my button for the second time. Does inside click blocks parent click? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call ajax inside `click` event and then run code there

```
$('#fileInputShp').click(function() {
 //here call AJAX;
 //ajax call;
});
```

more detail can found here [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Don't foregt to load `jQuery` Before that function call.

Comment: I Will try That in the moment but will this Ajax call be waiting for selection of the file?

Comment: you should check if the file are selected or not yet before call ajax ? and also you need to find how to pass that with AJAX.

Comment: Ok, and can you tell me why doSomething stops after second click()  and continues on second click of the button?

Comment: soSomething didn't call at all, can you add example code. I can't know more than what you added.

Comment: Ive got a button with doSomething on click

Comment: you don't need that function as you already have `input` with `type="file"`
or you can do `doSomething() { 
$('#fileInputShp').click(function() {
 //here call AJAX;
 //ajax call;
});
}`